# Strapi v4: Creating admin and adding Roles & Permissions while Bootstraping in strapi

Tags: node.js, typescript, strapi

Project is based on Typescript
Bootstrap all data for development purpose so that, whoever new working on the project will not be needed to insert all data in strapi admin panel.
Inserting an new data works fine but only when there is admin user is created. I am not able to create admin and roles from code please help.

below is the bootsrap function, currently i am coping .db file which is already filled with define data of admin and roles. Problem with this approach is there is no control over data. Need to fill admin and roles data from code like below i have done with home-page

`

```
async bootstrap() {
    try {
      const isFirst = await isFirstRun();

      if (isFirst && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        await fs.copyFileSync('./data/data.db', './.tmp/data.db');
        const data = await getHomePage();
        await strapi.services['api::home-page.home-page'].createOrUpdate({
          data,
        });

        console.log(
          '\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m',
          `Development data copied successfully \nAdmin:${process.env.ADMIN} \npassword: ${process.env.ADMIN_PASS}`,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
};
```

`

Tried https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3365 this but it's not working for me.
Tried other solutions but not working with strapi v4

Answer (score 0):

You should use `admin::user` service ([documentation on usage of services](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/services#usage)) to create an admin:

```js
// src/bootstrap.ts
export async function bootstrap({ strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) {

  // ...

  const hasAdmin = await strapi.service("admin::user").exists();

  if (hasAdmin) {
    console.log("Admin already created, skipping...");
    return;
  }

  const superAdminRole = await strapi.service("admin::role").getSuperAdmin();

  await strapi.service("admin::user").create({
    email: "x@x.x",
    firstname: "Test",
    lastname: "Admin",
    password: "password",
    registrationToken: null,
    isActive: true,
    roles: [superAdminRole.id],
  });

  // ...
}
```

Similarly, for creating new admin roles, use `admin:role` service:

```js
await strapi.service("admin::role").create({
  name: "Custom Editor",
  code: "custom-editor",
  description: "Custom editor role.",
});
```